# Displaying data that appears more than two times

Tags: ms-access

```
SELECT FirstName, LastName
FROM PATIENT
WHERE PATIENT.PatientID = VISIT.PatientID (select *
from VISIT
where PatientID in (select PatientID
                       from VISIT
                       group by PatientID
                       having count(*) > 1));
```

I need to make a code that displays patients' first and last names who visited a hospital more than twice. So far, this is the code I've created and now I want to ask how I should change this code to connect patient ID numbers in the PATIENT table to patient ID numbers in the VISIT table.

I've tried

```
PATIENT.PatientID = VISIT.PatientID
```

but it only shows an error message like this: "Undefined function  in expression"

How should I make it works properly?

Answer (score 1):

Try using `IN ...`:

```sql
SELECT 
    FirstName, 
    LastName
FROM 
    PATIENT
WHERE 
    PATIENT.PatientID IN 
        (select PatientID
        from VISIT
        group by PatientID
        having count(*) > 1);
```

Comment: Oh thank you so much! Now it works perfectly. If you don't mind, can you briefly explain what you did on your code? @Gustav

Comment: I used your subquery which returns the PatientIDs to be listed. Then, the `WHERE` clause uses `IN` to filter the PATIENT table on those PatientIDs.